# I tried delimiting the column and multiplying its numerical values to get square feet area but it's not working can somebody can correct me

Tags: sql

I wanted to delimit a complete column for example 12'x16' is in one cell so delimit and multiple 12*16 to get total area for that particular length and width .
I tried with the code below but it's not working and please help

Code is this

```
select 
  TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(size_name,1,INSTR(size_name,'''')-1))*
  TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(size_name,INSTR(siz_ename,'*')+1 ,
  INSTR(size_name,'''',1,2)-INSTR(size_name,'*',1)-1)) as square_feet_Area,     
  size_name, 
  asin  
From 
Table name     
Where ASIN in 
(
    'B01DZZ3TZ4','B01MS3QHR9','B01N3095SX','B084KGNGRB'
)    
Group by
  Asin,
  square_feet_Area,
  size_name
```

Comment: Unlike every other language, in SQL the second parameter of `SUBSTR` is the *length*, not *end index*

Comment: What is a "cell"?  Sample data and desired results in tabular format would help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used there.)

Answer (score 0):

Split the calculation into its separate parts so you can tell which parts are/aren't working e.g.

```
select 
  TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(size_name,1,INSTR(size_name,'''')-1)) as Part1
  TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(size_name,INSTR(siz_ename,'*')+1 ,
  INSTR(size_name,'''',1,2)-INSTR(size_name,'*',1)-1)) as Part2,     
  size_name, 
  asin  
From 
Table name
```